# How can I require authentication for my Angular templates?

Tags: angularjs, security

In my Angular (1.3) app, when the user navigates to a certain route, an XHR request is made for the template specified by `templateUrl` independently of whether the user is authenticated or not.

I don't want an unauthenticated user to be able to open up the Network tab in the developer toolbar and see the template code.

How do I make it so no XHR request is fired for `templateUrl` unless my user is authenticated?

I hope it's clear that I'm not asking *how* to do the authentication. I'm just asking how to put something between visiting the route and firing the template XHR request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yon can try with Angular Interceptors that can be used to intercept `$http` calls. It can be registered with [$httpProvider](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.19/docs/api/ng/provider/$httpProvider)

[Complete Example](http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/)

Sample code:

```
module.factory('myInterceptor', ['$q', 'userAsyncService', function($q, userAsyncService) {  
    var requestInterceptor = {
        request: function(config) {
            // put check on requested url if needed from config
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            // check for user validation here
            userAsyncService.isValidUser().then(function(valid) {   
                if(valid) {
                    deferred.resolve(config);
                } else {
                    // reject the request
                    deferred.reject(config);
                }                   
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
    return requestInterceptor;
}]);

module.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {  
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myInterceptor');
}]);
```

Comment: I'll accept this because I did end up using an interceptor, although my interceptor turned out to be quite a bit different.

Answer (score 1):

I use $cookie, before to do any request check the cookie and if exists he is logged and if doesn't he doesn't it.

You have to save the cookie in the system when the user have been logged.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

Comment: What I'm asking about isn't the part where you _set_ whether the user is logged in, but where you _check_ whether the user is logged in. Specifically, I need to check to see if the user is logged in before Angular attempts to retrieve the template.